# Passing a carbon date as a prop would return a computation in the vue template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I want to ask if how do you make this one work out

```html
:birthdate="{{ $user->profile->birthdate->format('m-d-Y') }}"
```

and In my model I have this

```
/**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    *//**
    */
    protected $dates = [
        'birthdate',
    ];
```

I want to pass it as a prop in my vue template

```js
props : { 
        birthdate : {   
            type : String, 
            required : true ,
            default : null
        }
    }
```

But instead I get a computation depends on the prop.. Just look at that :birthdate prop that I told you if I put it like m/d/Y it would divide the whole thing so if it's like `12/21/2019` it would divide it and if it's like `12-21-2019` it would subtract the whole thing when it's passed on the vue template

Answer (score 0):

Try removing [vue](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html) binding `:` and use it as:

```js
birthdate="{{ $user->profile->birthdate->format('m-d-Y') }}"
```

or keep `:` but wrap your string in single quotes.

```js
:birthdate="'{{ $user->profile->birthdate->format('m-d-Y') }}'"
```

Or assign to a variable

```js
:birthdate="myVar"

data(){
return{ myVar: "{{ $user->profile->birthdate->format('m-d-Y') }}"};
}
```

Because `:` or `v-bind` expects expression/variable, when you echo from PHP `{{ $user->profile->birthdate->format('m-d-Y') }}` as `12-21-2019` vue treats as integers with subtract not as string.